# How to install 'conans' python package into the system?

Tags: python, conan

I cannot find the module named 'conans' which is used by [conan package manager](https://conan.io/) for its recipes. I want to get autocompletion working while i writing `conanfile.py`
Tried `pip3 install conans` and `pip install conans` - "`ERROR: No matching distribution found for conans`"

Comment: conans comes with Conan (it's required for it to work)

Comment: My IDEs don't detect conans import. I'm sure that it is somewhere at the disk on my pc and is used as a local file but i want it to be visible and importable globally

Comment: Assuming you're on a UNIX-like distro (or have access to UNIX command line tools), take a look at `cat $(which conan)` and `locate conans`. `conans` should exist under `site-packages` whereever your Python install is (or whereever your virtualenv of whatever type is), and you'll also notice that the conan executable relies on `conans`.

Comment: Honestly though, you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info); you want autocomplete for `conanfile`, not how to install `conans`. I suggest asking about that instead of your attempted solution, and you might get some more relevant answers than "you already have it".

Comment: Check in your IDE which python interpreter it is using. Make sure it is the same one where conan is actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to install `conan` (without the "s") via

```
pip3 install conan
```

This includes both the CLI called `conan` and the python package called `conans`

Comment: It installs `conan` itself with binaries, etc.. `conans` package is included in it but still not visible for interpreter globally

Comment: @Herrgott it depends on how you installed conan. If you used pip you must use the same python interpreter and `conans` should be available

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, and I had to remove completely conan. In my case, I removed version 1 and 2:

```
$ rm /home/tarod/.local/bin/conan
$ rm -rfv ./conan
$ rm -rfv ./conan2
```

After that, install again conan:

```
$  pip install conan
```

I'm using pyenv as virtualenv for Python.

Comment: AFAIK, pip now uses version 2 and they added public API for recipes in that version